# dock div to right issue

Tags: css, html

I have a div that I need to dock to the right.

This is what I did:

```
<div style="float:right">
```

and although it does put the div on the right, it puts at the bottom. I already have a div and I want the right div to start at the top just like the left one, but it is starting at the bottom.

Here is how it looks:

```
|      |
|      |
|______|    |      |
            |      |
            |______|
```

Please help me.

Comment: please show us all of the html and css if you want us to help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep source order independence, give the floated `div` a negative `margin` equal to the `height` of the first `div`.

`.top {float:right; margin-top:-200px;}`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ztrap/)

Answer (score 2):

Place your right div before the other one.

Answer (score 0):

`<div style="float:left">` For the left,
`<div style="float:right">` For the right.